# Matplotlib Python exporting plot to png file and opening on computer

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to export plots in a for loop to png files that I can open on my computer. When I try and open the file, it is written as text and not as an image. Below is the plt.savefig code I am using to save my files.

```
plt.savefig(path+file, format='png')
```

Comment: Take an image viewer or browser, click file/open.. and select your saved image. It will be an image.

Comment: shouldn't the image be saved as a png and be able to open on its own?

Comment: This totally depends on settings within your operating system. Can you open any other png on your disk?

Comment: yes, the problem is that the files are saving as documents and not png files (update: I found the issue)

Comment: I think you misunderstand your operating system. The files are saved as png. However I can sure take any image file and name it `image.doc`. Seeing the extension `.doc` my operating system may think that it is a document to open with some typewriter software that is installed. It is of course your own duty to make sure to name the files with the respective extension if you want them to be managed by your operating system.